# Cancel Or Exit from PromptDialog.Choice Flow in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: frameworks, botframework, bots

i have a Prompt with 4 options, the last option is user can quit the Prompt,
i want to implement some code so that the bot exit the Prompt

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uoEu.png)

```
   PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, new List<string>() { FlightsOption, HotelsOption, TrainOption, GobackOption }, "Sure..! Tell me what booking would like to make..?", "Not a valid option", 3);
```

in above image i had implemented quit option on which if user selects quit it goes to Switch case of quit.

i had also tried context.quit but it throws error

```
private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        try
        {
            string optionSelected = await result;

            switch (optionSelected)
            {
                case FlightsOption:
                    context.Call(new FlightDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;

                case HotelsOption:
                    context.Call(new HotelsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;
                case TrainOption:
                    context.Call(new TrainDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;
                case GobackOption:
                    //want some code here to quit the form
                    break;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that we are not on your machine: add your code and an explicit problematic

Comment: i edited my code please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is not a Form Flow. This is prompt.
Now You can do something like, either you exit the dialog from the stack like this

```
try
        {
            string optionSelected = await result;

            switch (optionSelected)
            {
                case FlightsOption:
                    context.Call(new FlightDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;

                case HotelsOption:
                    context.Call(new HotelsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;
                case TrainOption:
                    context.Call(new TrainDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                    break;
                case GobackOption:
                    context.Done<object>(null);
                    break;


            }
        }
```

Or,
You can tell something and then wait for other message in the same dialog like this

```
 try
    {
        string optionSelected = await result;

        switch (optionSelected)
        {
            case FlightsOption:
                context.Call(new FlightDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                break;

            case HotelsOption:
                context.Call(new HotelsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                break;
            case TrainOption:
                context.Call(new TrainDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                break;
            case GobackOption:
            await context.PostAsync("Ok, you came back. Now tell something new.");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            break;
        }
    }
```

And the next message will go here

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
```